# Dual monitor (HDMI, DVI), DVI not showing

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, amd-radeon

Today I bought a Samsung Syncmaster S24B150 (with 1 DVI and 1 VGA port), my Windows 7  desktop (Dell XPS 8500) has a Radeon AMD 7850 graphical card with 1 HDMI and 1 DVI port, I'm using a newly bought König CABLE-193/3 DVI-D 24+1pin male to DVI-D 24+1pin male.

My second screen (the samsung synmaster, DVI connected) does not show anything.

When I let windows detect my displays, it succesfuly finds the monitor:

[image]

I can also succesfuly make screenshots ranging both screens.

[image]

When I connect the samsung syncmaster via VGA to my laptop the screen works as should.

When I unplug the HDMI monitor, I still don't get anything on my DVI monitor.

Answer (score 2):

Some ideas, in no particular order:

Ensure the monitor doesn't have a manual input toggle. If it does, ensure it's set to DVI.

Try a different (known good) DVI cable, or try your new cable on a different computer with a different (known working) DVI video adapter and monitor.

Try the monitor with a known good DVI cable on a system with a known good DVI video adapter.

Try a known-good DVi cable/monitor with your DVI video adapter.

Go through [Samsung's monitor troubleshooting](http://support-us.samsung.com/cyber/popup/iframe/pop_troubleshooting_fr.jsp?idx=1&modelname=T24B350ND&modelcode=&session_id=S4jdQV1YQHL1zLrckTZjDLNYPdVLsqDfLxFzQ2nXqQqBVc213ZlZ!-1930397578!1664967185!1379460061312&from_osc=).

Take it back because it's broken. ;)